Getting the error munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007ffe53bfa2c0 *** but not using free or malloc
When i do rosrun i get the error of the title but I'm using smart pointers so I don't know why it appears and I'm not using free or malloc. It's about hole avoidance using a robot. IT receives a point cloud and a costmap and tries to change the costmap values when there's a hole so it should avoid it by move_base.

std::shared_ptr<nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid> costmap_p = std::make_shared<nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid>();
std::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>> nubeDePuntos_p = std::make_shared<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>>();
std::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>> nube_filt = std::make_shared<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>>();
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> output_cloud;
// output_cloud.width = 0;  // Inicializa el ancho como 0
// output_cloud.height = 0; // Inicializa la altura como 0
// output_cloud.points.resize(0); // Inicializa el vector de puntos con tamano 0
nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid dev;
//costmap_2d::Costmap2D tf_costmap;
//tf::TransformListener* tf_listener = nullptr; 

costmap_2d::Costmap2D tf_costmap(1, 1, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0); // Valores predeterminados arbitrarios 
std::mutex mtx;

//tf::TransformListener tf_listener;
//nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid* occupancy_grid = malloc(100*sizeof(nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid));

// Funcion para convertir un nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid a un costmap_2d::Costmap2D
costmap_2d::Costmap2D convertirACostmap2D( nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid occupancy_grid, tf::TransformListener& tf) {
    //auto costmap = std::make_shared<costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS>("mi_costmap", tf);
    //ROS_INFO("no");
    costmap_2d::Costmap2D costmap_data(occupancy_grid.info.width, occupancy_grid.info.height, 
                                        occupancy_grid.info.resolution, 
                                        occupancy_grid.info.origin.position.x, 
                                        occupancy_grid.info.origin.position.y);

    // Copiar los datos de ocupacion del mensaje OccupancyGrid al Costmap2D
    for(unsigned int x = 0; x < occupancy_grid.info.width; ++x) {
        for(unsigned int y = 0; y < occupancy_grid.info.height; ++y) {
            int8_t occupancy_value = occupancy_grid.data[x + y * occupancy_grid.info.width];
            unsigned char cost = costmap_2d::FREE_SPACE; // Por defecto, se considera celda libre

            if (occupancy_value == 100) {
                cost = costmap_2d::LETHAL_OBSTACLE; // Si es 100, se considera un obstaculo letal
            } else if (occupancy_value > 0) {
                cost = costmap_2d::INSCRIBED_INFLATED_OBSTACLE; // Si es mayor que 0, se considera un obstaculo inscrito
            }

            costmap_data.setCost(x, y, cost);
        }
    }

    //costmap->updateMap();
    return costmap_data;
}


nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid cambia(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> input_cloud,
                               nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid costmap_data,
                               pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> nube_filter) {
    std::size_t i = 1;
    tf::TransformListener tf_listener;
       

    if (input_cloud.points.empty() || costmap_data.data.empty()) { 
        ROS_WARN("La nube de puntos esta vacia."); 
    return costmap_data; }  

    //Extraccion de coordenadas
    for(auto& point : input_cloud.points){
        //Conversion a costmap 2d
        
        double costmap_x = point.x;
        double costmap_y = point.y;
        int width = costmap_data.info.width;
        int height = costmap_data.info.height;

        // Calcula el indice correspondiente a la posicion (costmap_x, costmap_y)
        int index = static_cast<int>(costmap_x) + static_cast<int>(costmap_y) * width; // Verificar que el índice esté dentro de los límites del costmap 
        if(index >= 0 && index < static_cast<int>(costmap_data.data.size())) { // Operar solo si el índice es válido // Modifica el valor en el índice correspondiente del costmap 
   

        // Asegurate de que el indice este dentro de los limites del array de datos

        if(pcl_isfinite(point.x) && pcl_isfinite(point.y) && pcl_isfinite(point.z)){
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
            //ROS_INFO("paso");
            tf_costmap = convertirACostmap2D(costmap_data, tf_listener);
            // Accede y modifica el valor del mapa en la posicion (costmap_x, costmap_y)
            // if(index>=0 && index<costmap_data.data.size())
            //     tf_costmap.setCost(costmap_x, costmap_y, 255);
            // i = i+1;
            //std::cout<<tf_costmap<<std::endl;
            //costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS costmap_final("costmapfinal", tf_listener);
        }
        }
    // Copiar los datos del costmap a los datos de la grid de ocupacion
    //ROS_INFO("no");
    if(i >= input_cloud.size()){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        //ROS_INFO("%lu", input_cloud.size());
        costmap_data.data.resize(tf_costmap.getSizeInCellsX() * tf_costmap.getSizeInCellsY());
        for (unsigned int y = 0; y < tf_costmap.getSizeInCellsY(); ++y) {
            for (unsigned int x = 0; x < tf_costmap.getSizeInCellsX(); ++x) {
                ROS_INFO("paso");
                unsigned int costmap_index = tf_costmap.getIndex(x, y);
                unsigned char cost = tf_costmap.getCost(x, y);
                if (cost == costmap_2d::LETHAL_OBSTACLE) {
                    costmap_data.data[y * tf_costmap.getSizeInCellsX() + x] = 100; // Celda ocupada
                } else if (cost == costmap_2d::INSCRIBED_INFLATED_OBSTACLE ||
                        cost == costmap_2d::NO_INFORMATION) {
                    costmap_data.data[y * tf_costmap.getSizeInCellsX() + x] = 100; // Celda desconocida
                } else {
                    costmap_data.data[y * tf_costmap.getSizeInCellsX() + x] = 100; // Celda libre
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    }
    //ROS_INFO("no");
    //pub.publish(dev);
    return costmap_data;

}

nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid Hole_fn(  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>& input_cloud_p,
                                  nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid& costmap_data_p,
                                  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>& nube_filt_p)
{
    //ros::Rate;
    //input_cloud_p.clear();
    ros::spinOnce();
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_out_ptr(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    // Filtro de muestreo para reducir la densidad
    pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PointXYZ> sor;
    sor.setInputCloud(input_cloud_p.makeShared());
    sor.setLeafSize(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);  // Ajusta el tamano del voxel segun tus necesidades
    sor.filter(*cloud_out_ptr);
    //ROS_INFO("%lu", input_cloud_p.size());
    if(input_cloud_p.size()>0)
        return cambia(*cloud_out_ptr, costmap_data_p, nube_filt_p);
}


void nubeCallback(const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr& dato1)
{     
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    if (!dato1 || dato1->points.empty()) { 
        ROS_WARN("Nube de puntos vacia o no inicializada."); 
    return; 
    } 
    // Filtrar pendientes
    *nubeDePuntos_p = *dato1;
    //ROS_INFO("%lu", nubeDePuntos_p.size());
    // Publicar la nube de puntos filtrada si es necesario
    Hole_fn(*nubeDePuntos_p, *costmap_p, *nube_filt); 
}

void nubeCallback2(const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr& dato1)
{   
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);  
    // Filtrar pendientes
    if (!dato1 || dato1->points.empty()) { 
        ROS_WARN("Nube de puntos vacia o no inicializada."); 
    return; 
    } 
    *nube_filt = *dato1;
    // Publicar la nube de puntos filtrada si es necesario
    Hole_fn(*nubeDePuntos_p, *costmap_p, *nube_filt);
}

void costmapCallback(const nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid::ConstPtr& dato2)
{     
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);

    if (!dato2) { 
        ROS_WARN("El mensaje OccupancyGrid es nulo."); 
        return; 
    }  

    // Filtrar pendientes
    *costmap_p = *dato2;
    // Publicar la nube de puntos filtrada si es necesario
    Hole_fn(*nubeDePuntos_p, *costmap_p, *nube_filt);}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "hole_node");
    //HoleDetectionNode node;
    ros::NodeHandle nh2;
    ros::Publisher pub;
    ros::Subscriber sub = nh2.subscribe<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>>("/robot/front_rgbd_camera/depth/points", 1000, nubeCallback);
    ros::Subscriber sub2 = nh2.subscribe<nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid>("/robot/move_base/local_costmap/costmap", 1000, costmapCallback);
    ros::Subscriber sub3 = nh2.subscribe<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>>("/nube_hole_topic", 1000, nubeCallback2);
    //pub = nh2.advertise<nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid>("/robot/nube_filtrada1", 1000);
    //pub.publish(dev);
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}

I've tried to use mutex and that stuff but nothing works

If you're using std::shared_ptr then you're indirectly using dynamic memory allocation. The error you get is typical when you write out of bounds of dynamically allocated memory. I recommend you build with a sanitizer to help find where it might happen (for GCC and Clang, add the flags -g -fsanitize=address,undefined).

You still use new too ...
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_out_ptr(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);. Are you sure your PointXYZ follows the rule of 0,3,5? (e.g. if the class is copied... do you make a new copy. If not you can get double deletes. Rule of thumb, don't use new/delete either but use std::make_unique or std::make_shared

@PepijnKramer is probably right with the rules of 3/5/0. You pass objects by value, objects which seem to contain pointers (for example nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid occupancy_grid).

Thanks both of u, I've being investigating what rule of 0,3,5 is, cause i didn't know. But I don't how to apply it. If you have time, I would appreciate it if you explain it.

I have substituted the line with the "new" with this "pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ::Ptr cloud_out_ptr = boost::make_shared<pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ>();" but the problem persists. Is there anything I could change too? @PepijnKramer

@Someprogrammerdude I mention u here because I couldnt in the previous comment. Do you know what could i do next?

@Diego pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr is a typedef for a shared ptr. Without seeing all the code it seems likely to me that you're doing something with cloud_out_ptr after it's gone out of scope.
